# mean calculation of a vector in R

Tags: r, vector, mean

I am trying to figure out how can i calculate the `mean` of a vector.

Vector is `S1temp` which prints `[1] "18, 20.5, 18, 18.6, 21.5"`. I 've read searched for a solution but `as.numeric` and `suppressWarnings` does not work.

Is there an other way to do achieve this?

thanks,

Comment: It looks like your vector may be a string. Try `strsplit` to break up your character into a vector of numerics.

Comment: @GaryWeissman `strsplit` generated this `[1] "18,"   "20.5," "18,"   "18.6," "21.5"` and gives the same error

Comment: @GaryWeissman would removing `,` from inside of each values `""` fix this? how can i do this?

Comment: Try it with `split=','` and then `as.numeric` and you'll be left with a vector of number for which you can use the function `mean` to get your result

Comment: @GaryWeissman Can you show the whole thing please?

Comment: I only have my phone on me; when I get to a computer I'll type it out.

Comment: @GaryWeissman its ok someone got inspired by your feedback and gave an answer. ty

Comment: I'm tempted to add "plot twist: the vector turns out to be a string" to the title :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
as.numeric(unlist((strsplit(S1temp,",")))
```

Comment: Oh well too slow phone

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `strsplit` here is to just use `scan`:

```
S1temp
# [1] "18, 20.5, 18, 18.6, 21.5"

X <- scan(text = S1temp, sep = ",")
# Read 5 items

X
# [1] 18.0 20.5 18.0 18.6 21.5

str(X)
#  num [1:5] 18 20.5 18 18.6 21.5
```